# Shortcut LINQ toentity query for the following code in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

[image: Database model for entities]

I have entities which are indeirectly connected. Here, **Task** is connected to **Sprint** indirectly. One **BacklogItem** can have several **Task** and each **BacklogItem** belongs to one **Sprint**. So, In my application I needed all the Tasks belonging to some sprint. Since they do not connect directly, I had to write a many code lines which is below:

```
public viewResult tasksForSprint(int sprintId){
List<Task> tasksforSprint = new List<Task>();

var backlogItemlsit = db.BacklogItems.Where(b => b.sprintId == sprintId).OrderBy(i => i.backlogId).ToList();
var sprintTaskItems = db.Tasks.OrderBy(i => i.taskId).ToList();
foreach (var item in sprintTaskItems)
{
            if (backlogItemlsit.Any(b => b.backlogId == item.backlogId))
                taskforSprint.Add(item);
}
return view(tasksforSprint);
}
```

Now, what I want is get that List tasksforSprint with one LINQ query rather than 6 lines of code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a join.  Untested:

```
db.BacklogItems
    .Where(b => b.sprintId == sprintId)
    .Join(db.Tasks, 

        // outer join key
        sprint => sprint.backlogId, 

        // inner join key
        task => task.backlogId,

        // result selector -- take the tasks
        (outer, inner) => inner)
.OrderBy(task => task.taskId)    
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I got the idea now.